# SharePoint PropertyBag Settings 2010 access denied 0x80070005

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, propertybag

I'm trying to get [SharePoint PropertyBag Settings 2010](http://Unknown%20SPRequest%20error%20occurred.%20More%20information%3a%200x80070005) working in my Central Administration site, and it seems to be working, at least partly.  However, there's a problem: when I click the web application dropdown and select a web application (on :8000) I get this access denied error:

```
Site Enumeration Stack:   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseCollection.GetEnumerator()    
 at ASP._admin_pbs2010_propertybagssettings_aspx.ddlWebApplications_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.RaiseChangedEvents()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    
 at ASP._admin_pbs2010_propertybagssettings_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)    
 at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

Followed by:

```
Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070005
```

The strange thing is that on another web application (:80), it all works just fine.  The only appreciable difference between these sites is that :8000 is configured for both Windows auth and forms auth, while :80 is Windows auth only.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a patch that just came out that fixed this issue for me.  Check out http://pbs2010.codeplex.com/workitem/7839

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to this codeplex project: http://pbs2010.codeplex.com/ If so, you might want to try posting in the discussions for the original author of the code to answer http://pbs2010.codeplex.com/discussions Otherwise, I suggest you check out the MS Patterns and Practice Group SharePoint Guidance project: http://spg.codeplex.com/ It also has code for property bags and you may find it more reliable.